# Viewer doesn`t show the model on latest libs - on some browsers (especially mobile)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Hi I have specific problem, when i`m trying to run my project on tablets and surfaces i have error:

```
viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:1372 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null
at _.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:1372)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at g (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:1372)
at f (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:1372)
at _.recognizeWith (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:1372)
at new Autodesk.Viewing.GestureHandler (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:13874)
at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.createControls (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:42281)
at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:42354)
at GuiViewer3D.initialize (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:48392)
at GuiViewer3D.Viewer3D.start (viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*:42154)
```

this error occurs until version 2.13, when im using v2.12 everything is fine.

I want to use most recent api, because i see that on newer libs everything work better

could you help me in some way

//script loading

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/three.js?v=2.12.*"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=2.12.*"></script>
```

i tried also

```
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/three.js?v=3.1.*"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=3.1.*"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show me how you are loading the scripts? You might be using an old version of the loading mechanism as well. Any link to a public repo where I can see this.

Comment: updated of script loading

Comment: Are you still having this problem. your comment from above does not tell me much if you still need help with this.

Comment: previous comment was only for trigger notification that i updated my question, and now you can see in what way im loading scripts. This problem still exists.

Comment: damn. i found out what was the problem... the problem was external lib -> materialize.js, when i used it i had that error, now i throw it and it is ok now. Sorry for littering the forum...

Comment: Hah that happens often :) it's ok. glad you were able to find the problem and you are now unblocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was caused by a 3rd party library. *"the problem was external lib -> materialize.js, when i used it i had that error, now i throw it and it is ok now."*